# Alias column name to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I've in my code something like that:

TagsController

```
@tag = Tag.find(id: Tag.root)
```

tag.rb

```
def self.root
  TagHierarchy.select('ancestor_id').where(generations: 0)  
end
```

The problem is:

`Couldn't find Tag with 'id'={:id=>#<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<TagHierarchy ancestor_id: 1>]>}`

So I need to alias the column name `ancestor_id` to `id` but I don't know how to..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out, may be this will help you out

```
def self.root
  TagHierarchy.where(generations: 0).first.ancestor_id
end
```